# Fortify - Trust Boundary Violation - Asp.net(C#)- string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, fortify

In Properties I have set value to session its working fine as expected but when I run the fortify scan its showing "Trust Boundary Violation" issue. I tried searching for the related issue but i am not getting the exact approach for this. Kindly assist me. Please look into below code

```
    private string xxx
     {
        get
        {
            if (Session["_xyz"] != null)
            {
                return (string) Session["_xyz"];
            }
            return null;
        }

        set { Session["_xyz"] = value; }
    }
```

Fortify scan shows issue Like,

```
The method set_xxx() in xyz.aspx.cs commingles trusted and untrusted data in the same data structure, which encourages programmers to mistakenly trust unvalidated data.
```